# "Series" – a noun of multitude similar to "lot", "majority", "percentage", "proportion"– verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases, irregular-plurals

According to Garner's fourth edition

> Though serving as a plural when the need arises, *series* is ordinarily
> a singular noun. But it is also a noun of
> multitude, so that phrases such as *a series of things* take a plural
> verb. However, the collocation *there {has been - is} a series* has predominated
> in print sources.
>
> Common nouns of
> multitude: *lot, majority, mass, minority, multitude,
> percentage, proportion, variety*.

However, [the entry of series of the American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=series) reads

> When it has the singular sense of "one set," it takes a singular verb,
> even when *series* is followed by *of* and a plural noun: *A series of
> lectures is scheduled.*

**Are these dissimilar usages stylic advice?**

Secondly, the inversion after *there* also chooses singular elsewhere; why is it so?

> When the verb precedes the noun *percentage*, a singular verb is required. That is, *a higher percentage of them **are***, but *there **is** a higher percentage of them*.

Comment: I thought that *followed by*  ***of*** was a typo in the transcription of the original text. On looking at it, I see that the original text puts it in italics, having it make sense rather than appear ungrammatical. Please accurately transcribe the original text, including its presentation (italics in this case), so as to preserve the original meaning.

Comment: Also, please quote the *entire* paragraph of that text so as to put it in the proper context. By leaving out the entire paragraph, you are severely distorting what that dictionary is trying to communicate. (Since you don't provide a link to the first text, I'm not sure what you might have left out. But this seems to be a pattern with your posts, and I wouldn't be surprised if something important is missing.)

Comment: Why do you think that "series" is similar to "lot"?